# Django sorl-thumbnail generating wrong sized thumbnails

Tags: django, image-processing, python-imaging-library, sorl-thumbnail

I have an image here, i uploaded it to dropbox with same name at server:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q2v8b7jrznyvh68/aaacc6460e2e4a0aa653fa8bbaa59f61?dl=0

The problem is, i'm getting thumbnail of this image with this command:

```
thmb = get_thumbnail(img, '220')
```

Expecting that thumbnail width will be 220, but...

```
> thmb.width
70
```

Original image size is 1836 × 3264 pixels. Size of thumbnail should be:

```
ratio = 220 / 1836 = 0.11982570806100218
(1836 * ratio)X(3264 * ratio) =  220X391 pixels.
```

Do you have any idea about what is wrong there?

Comment: Are you sure it's the right image? Like it's showing you a small copy of the original? Just checking.

Comment: Do you mean image at link? yes its right. You have to click download button.

Comment: No I meant sorl-thumbnail. Have you viewed the output image?

Comment: yes, its size of 70x124